# Move element from one array to another

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have this array:

```
$arr1 = array(
 '76' => '1sdf',
 '43' => 'sdf2',
 '34' => 'sdf2',
 '54' => 'sdfsdf2',
 '53' => '2ssdf',
 '62' => 'sfds'
);
```

What I want to do is take the first 3 elements, remove them and create a new array with them.

So you would have this:

```
$arr1 = array(
  '54' => 'sdfsdf2',
  '53' => '2ssdf',
  '62' => 'sfds'
);

$arr2 = array(
  '76' => '1sdf',
  '43' => 'sdf2',
  '34' => 'sdf2'
);
```

How can I perform this action
Thanks

Comment: And what is the problem exactly?

Comment: how would i perform this task

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: This is a perfectly straight forward question, that I myself am having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code should serve your purpose:

```
$arr1 = array(
 '76' => '1sdf',
 '43' => 'sdf2',
 '34' => 'sdf2',
 '54' => 'sdfsdf2',
 '53' => '2ssdf',
 '62' => 'sfds'
); // the first array
$arr2 = array(); // the second array
$num = 0; // a variable to count the number of iterations
foreach($arr1 as $key => $val){
  if(++$num > 3) break; // we don’t need more than three iterations
  $arr2[$key] = $val; // copy the key and value from the first array to the second
  unset($arr1[$key]); // remove the key and value from the first
}
print_r($arr1); // output the first array
print_r($arr2); // output the second array
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [54] => sdfsdf2
    [53] => 2ssdf
    [62] => sfds
)
Array
(
    [76] => 1sdf
    [43] => sdf2
    [34] => sdf2
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/102083)

Comment: Dear downvoter, may I know what’s wrong with my answer?

Comment: Too quick to judge and downvote but never provide an answer that may be better

Comment: His response is exactly what i'm looking for

Answer (score 5):

[`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) will copy the first *x* elements of `$arr1` into `$arr2`, and then you can use [`array_diff_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) to remove those items from `$arr1`. The second function will compare both keys and values to ensure that only the appropriate elements are removed.

```
$x    = 3;
$arr2 = array_slice($arr1, 0, $x, true);
$arr1 = array_diff_assoc($arr1, $arr2);
```