# PHP split array into 2 arrays by value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to implement this so here it is. I have an array

```
$arr = array("purchase_order_details_id"=>array(
               0=>"POD1",
               1=>"POD1",
               2=>"POD2",
           ),
            "quantity_received"=>array(
               0=>5,
               1=>10,
               2=>20
            )
         );
```

I want to split the arrays into two. Into something like this.

```
$pod_2 = array("purchase_order_details_id"=>array(
       0=>"POD1",
       1=>"POD1"
       ),
       "quantity_received"=>array(
       0=>5,
       1=>10
       ));

$pod_1 = array("purchase_order_details_id"=>array(
       2=>"POD2"
       ),
       "quantity_received"=>array(
       2=>20
       ));
```

Anyone has an idea on how to do this ? Any thoughts is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Already answered here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805954/move-element-from-one-array-to-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805954/move-element-from-one-array-to-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use array_intersect to find the POs in a loop of unique POs.
Then I use array_inyersect_key to get the quantity.
This requires only one iteration per unique Purchase_order_detali_id.
Meaning it has a much better performance than looping the full array.

Edit: added extract to create the two variables. But I would rather keep them in the array if I was you.

```
$pods = array_unique($arr["purchase_order_details_id"]);

Foreach($pods as $pod){
    $PO = array_intersect($arr["purchase_order_details_id"], [$pod]);
    $qt = array_intersect_key($arr["quantity_received"], $PO);
    $new[$pod] = ["purchase_order_details_id" => $PO, "quantity_received" => $qt];
}
Var_dump($new);
extract($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/dBpuJ

Answer (score 3):

Try with below code:

```
$array = array();   
foreach($arr['purchase_order_details_id'] as $key => $val)
{
    $array[$val]['purchase_order_details_id'][] = $val;
    $array[$val]['quantity_received'][] = $arr['quantity_received'][$key];
}

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

extract($array);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($POD1);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($POD2);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: are you sure? he said two

Comment: @AmrBerag yes, didnt notice it was just 1 array at first thought.

Comment: One option, you can `list($pod_2, $pod_1) = array_values($array);` to seperate the 2 arrays. +1

Comment: After that we can use `extract($array);` to split all arrays by key

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    $size = ceil(count($val) / 2);

    $arr2 = array_chunk($val, $size, true);

    $pod_2[$key] = $arr2[0];
    $pod_1[$key] = $arr2[1];
}

var_dump($pod_2);
var_dump($pod_1);
```

Comment: How did this answer get upvoted? This literally splits the array in half and does not care what POD it is. Top half is POD2  and bottom half is POD1, which also is incorrect.

Comment: @Andreas The answer looks like what was specified. Did you see something different when you tested the code?

Comment: See here: https://3v4l.org/G0NqF your values are incorrect, and if you change the order of the values it gets worse https://3v4l.org/1aoKN

Comment: Oh, I missed the phrase "by value" in the title. In that case, feel free to downvote.